# FabricJS 2 - Image isn't stretching to the given width

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

I have just upgraded from fabric 1.7 to 2 and now the image object is behaving differently.See the screenshot, the image where the arrow is is completely ignoring the fact that i set a width on it, it looks like it's actually scaling it based on the given height to keep the image ratio. I don't want this to happen, the image needs to stretch to the size i tell it to.

Anyone have any idea to stop it doing this? I mean if i set a width in the options for the image object i expect it to respect those dimensions. It should be stretching to fill where the red box is.

This is happening when loading the image initially as a square and setting {width:1000,height:400} for example, but instead it looks like it's taking the height and scaling the width down to keep it square.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `scaleX` for width and `scaleY` for height. It's a breaking [change](http://fabricjs.com/v2-breaking-changes) for v2.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var index = 0,
  json;
var url = '//fabricjs.com/assets/pug.jpg';

fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(img) {
  var elWidth = img.naturalWidth || img.width;
  var elHeight = img.naturalHeight || img.height;
  img.set({
    scaleX:200/elWidth,
    scaleY:200/elHeight
  })
  canvas.add(img);
})
```

```css
canvas{
 border:2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="
https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: ok that's a little difficult since we don't know what the size of the actual image is when fabric has kept the ratio? We give it the width and height we need and it just alters it so how do we know what scale factor to use? If the image is 400x400and i want to display at 1000x400 fabric is showing it as 400x400 based on the height it seems and only want the width to stretch to 1000 not 400

Comment: @GlenElkins I have used `200` for width and height, change as per your need.

Comment: thanks! i hate it when they do things like this, i want control not fabric

Comment: @GlenElkins, there is new crop feature added, so it got changed. Its all in that doc link i shared.

Comment: thanks, the crop feature sounds interesting, they also changed how clipTo works so i'll look into crop instead.